# Incomplete HTML via r.text from Django template with python-requests

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm using [python-requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to get HTML from a page and later extract some links from it.

Here's the modified part of the function:

```
# views.py

import requests

def my_function(request):

    page = requests.get("http://some/url")
    html = page.text
    print(html)
```

When I execute `my_function` via a `{% url 'url_name' %}` in the template file, the printed `page.text` doesn't contain part of the HTML code that should be visible on the `page`. It appears that the code that is missing is that is within `{% block content %} {% endblock content %}` in my template file.

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

*(I'm using Python 3.8.2, Django 3.0.6, requests 2.23.0)*